# How to display the login information in different layout?

Tags: java, android

I have created an application which needs sign in from Facebook/Twitter/Google to get started. In a layout I have created three **switches** each for Facebook, Twitter and Google which has options ON and OFF. I want to make the switch of the particular account as 'ON' if the user is logged in from that corresponding account. Example if the user is logged in from Facebook, only the switch beside Facebook should be ON. How can I do that?

Any suggestions would be appreciated, and also if somebody know then please refer me to any tutorial related to this.
Below is my code for the login page. I have shown the login for Facebook part:
Thanx :)

```
private OnClickListener loginButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onClick( View v ) {
            String[] permissions = { "offline_access", "publish_stream", "user_photos", "publish_checkins","photo_upload" };


            if(v.getId() == R.id.button1 )
            {
                facebookSwitch = true;
                twitterSwitch = false;
                googleSwitch = false;
                if( !mFacebook.isSessionValid() ) {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Authorizing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mFacebook.authorize(Login.this, permissions, new LoginDialogListener());
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText( Login.this, "Has valid session", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(mFacebook.request("me"));
                        //Log.d("Login", "11111111111111111");
                        String facebookID = json.getString("id");
                        //Log.d("Login", "22222222222222"); 

                        String firstName = json.getString("first_name");
                        //Log.d("Login", "3333333333333333333");

                        String lastName = json.getString("last_name");
                        //Log.d("Login", "4444444444444444444444");

                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "You already have a valid session, " + firstName + " " + lastName + ". No need to re-authorize.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    catch( Exception error ) {
                        Toast.makeText( Login.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    catch( FacebookError error ) {
                        Toast.makeText( Login.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way....

**-** First create a `Singleton Class` with 3 boolean`variables for 3 logins info, and there`Getter-Setter`. Singleton is needed over here **so that only One object of that class is formed no matter from where that class is called in the whole application**. So now you have a single point of info.

**-** Always check `Singleton` Class's variables in the beginning of another `Activity` or when needed by you, to know that whether the user is logged into one or two or all the social networking sites.

**////////////////////////////////Edited Part/////////////////////////////**

**A simple way of creating a Singleton is below, thought there are few more:**

```
public class Test{

   public static Test uniqueInstance = new Test();

   private Test(){}

   public static Test getInstance(){

      return uniqueInstance;       

      // No matter what but always u will get the same instance.

   }

}
```

**Now To call this object in another class do as below...**

```
public class Main{

 Test t = Test.getInstance();    // Now use t to call the fields and methods of class T.


}
```

Comment: @Aashish see the edited answer..so it would be better to refresh it before reading.